# Cache-control set to public, but Cache use Cookie for determining whether the Cache is valid

Tags: okhttp

when the client specifies the request Cache-control to be public and the server sets the response Cache-control to be public, then the Cache will still use the Cookie in the Vary header as its policy for determining whether the Cache is valid.Is this true?

In addition, okhttp still saves the response data when neither the request nor the response has the Cache-Control header set.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction of the problem that others can run. Have a read of http://sscce.org/ for advice on creating good questions for forums.


Also https://httpbin.org/ is a useful site to test against.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is avoided by modifying the Vary header on the server side and removing the Cookie option when Cache-Control sets public